# Postgres fetch exact ROW using JSON column

Tags: postgresql, json

I have records in table like below format.

Table struture

```
CREATE TABLE test.orders (
id serial NOT NULL,
info json NOT NULL,
value varchar NULL,
CONSTRAINT orders_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

);

[image]

If I pass value for info column `{"101":1}` then only value `s1` should be fetched not the others.

So is there any feasible way in postges to fetch exact this type of result?

Thanks

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can you help to solve this issue ?https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/258615/postgres-fetch-exact-value-when-satisfied-all-conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want those where the value matches exactly the key/value pair, use `=` with a `jsonb` type.

```
select *
from the_table
where info::jsonb = '{"101": 1}'
```

As your column is not defined as `jsonb` (which it should be) you have to cast it before you can compare it.

Comment: Question is updated with table structure and contains operator `@>`  supported in postgres verion 10.10?

Comment: @5a01d01P: yes, Postgres 10 supports `@>` but only for `jsonb` so you need to cast your column (as I already mentioned)

Comment: Your query is working but it gives me all records. If I pass `'{"101": 1}'` then only first row record should be return not other because other records have some additional values.

Comment: @5a01d01P: as I said that was unclear from your question. See my edit

Comment: Thanks a lot, Now one last thing if I create index on `info` column then  it will work for large record set?