# Postgres fetch exact value when satisfied all conditions

Tags: postgresql, query, group-by

Here are the table structure and sample data.

```
CREATE TABLE public.product (
                id serial NOT NULL,
                opid int4 NULL,
                opvalue int4 NULL,
                info varchar NULL,
                CONSTRAINT product_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
            );

INSERT INTO product (id,opid,opvalue,info) VALUES 
            (1,1,1,'s1')
            ,(2,1,1,'s2')
            ,(3,2,1,'s2')
            ,(4,1,1,'s3')
            ,(6,3,2,'s3')
            ,(5,2,1,'s3')
            ;
```

[image]

Now I want query if info value satisfied all it's condition value then it will be returned.
Ex.If I pass `opid=1 and opvalue=1` then only `s1` should be returned not `s2` because `s2` have it's different condition. `s1` should be returned when I pass `(opid=1 and opvalue =1) and (opid=2 and opvalue =1)`

Comment: What did you try yourself?

Comment: @Colin'tHart, I tried my below query.
`SELECT q1.info
FROM (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(opid)) as matched_count, info
FROM product
WHERE ((opid=1 and opvalue=1)  
and (opid=2 and opvalue =1))
 GROUP BY  info) q1 
JOIN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(opid)) as matched_count,  info 
FROM product
GROUP BY  info) q2
on q1.info = q2.info  and q1.matched_count = q2.matched_count;`

Comment: your table logic is flawed - alone your last sentences show that. You have ambiguous data each "info" requires its own select - as you have no easy way to ask for 2 or 3 different opid,opvalue pairs

Comment: @eagle275 then any other alternative way?

Comment: normalize data - the goal is to have data that have no deeper relationship as is visible in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is solved via creating one summary table of this table and manage count of info in parent table then using query on count of that parent table.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
select *
from product p
where opid = 1 and opvalue = 1
and not exists (
  select *
  from product x
  where x.info = p.info
  and (x.opid != p.opid or x.opvalue != p.opvalue)
);
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1efcb7a125d52c27b2c386307d37da5b

Comment: Colin'tHart, your query is right for `s1` value, but if I need `s2` then what? Note: I will pass only opid and opvalue.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte AS 
(
SELECT *,
       COUNT(info) OVER (PARTITION BY info) total_count,
       SUM(CASE WHEN opid=1 AND opvalue=1 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY info) conditional_count
FROM product
)
SELECT id, opid, opvalue, info
FROM cte
WHERE total_count = conditional_count;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0bbb6af7d4eb3ea36cc8ed93a01abc4e)

PS. If there exists more than one record which matches your conditions (full duplicate except `id` field) then remove `id` from output fields list and add DISTINCT.

Comment: Akina, your query is right for `s1` value, but if I need only` s2` then what should I do? Because if I add `WHEN opid=2 AND opvalue=1 THEN 1` in query then it gives me `s1&s2` both results.

Comment: @5a01d01P *but if I need only` s2` then what should I do?* What conditions you will use when you need `'s2'`? `opid=1 and opvalue=1` and records array for `s2` do not match each other in your *info value satisfied all it's condition value*.

Comment: I have to write query if I pass `opid=1 and 2, opvalue=1` then in this scenario only `s2` will be fetched not other.

Comment: @5a01d01P *if I pass `opid=1 and 2, opvalue=1` then* Of course, it is synthactically wrong.

Comment: Akina, I know, but I need some logic in the query to fulfill this condition.

Comment: @5a01d01P First thing which you must to do is to formalize your criteria for to be applicable by SQL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103931/discussion-between-5a01d01p-and-akina).